# Merging attribute tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, table

Currently, I have two attribute tables my vector table and an additional table for vector interaction. I was wondering if I could merge the attribute tables within the software.

As I would like to use the "Delete duplicate geometries" as some of the data would be reoccurring and would like to delete them without manually doing that. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at 'join' function. You need a matching field in both tables.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can merge them by going to:

```
Vector > Data management tools > Merge vector layers
```

you can also join two attribute tables in `Layer Properties` but as mentioned above you'll need a common field between attribute tables.

[image: properties > join]

To eliminate duplicate geometries you can both dissolve the layer by field:

```
Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Dissolve
```

or search for `Delete duplicate geometries` in the `Processing toolbox`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are six features in *'LayerA'* (there are two features with the same geometry, namely `"Name 5"`) and a CSV file (*'data'*) with some values that we are interested in, see image below. Instead of a CSV file can be a usual shapefile as well.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to join `"values"` from a CSV file*.

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.*,
    d."value"
FROM
    "LayerA" AS a
JOIN
    "data" AS d
        ON a."Name" = d."Name"
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table including new values will look as following

[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [A quick tutorial to SpatiaLite | 4. Performing some Spatial data analysis](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-tutorial-2.3.1.html#t4)
- [w3schools | SQL Tutorial | SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)